# How does the Archimedean property imply the following?

Tags: real-analysis

My book states that by the Archimedean Property, if given $\epsilon>0$ there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N$ implies $5/n < \epsilon/2$.

How can we arrive at this conclusion via the Archimedean property?

It follows that if $n>N$ then $1/n<1/N$, but from here I don't see where to apply the property.

Answer (score 1):

You can move $5$ to the other side: $1/n < \epsilon/10$.

It turns out that for any $a > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}\mid 1/n < a$, because you can choose $c\mid 0 < c < a$ using the Archimedean property, and let $n = \lceil c^{-1} \rceil$.

Answer (score 0):

Let 10 and ϵ > 0 be given. Then there exist 
n ∈ N such that nϵ > 10 or 10 < nϵ or 10/2 < nϵ/2 or 5 < nϵ/2 or 5/n < n/2 
Hence: 5/n<ϵ/2

Comment: The Archimedean Property of R allows us to obtain an n ∈ N such that nϵ > 10.

Comment: Please use MathJaX formatting and put all relevant info into your answer, itself!